# After back trace #0 0x00000000 in ?? () in GDB

Tags: gdb

My program is crashing some where, i tried to debug using GDB. when i use back-trace, it's just showing first line address

I compiled it by -g option. How would i find,where the exact core dump is happening.

Comment: It means your frame-pointer or stack, which contains the caller's return address, has corrupted, so GDB is not able to backward trace to callers. And your program jumps to illegal address in 0x00000000 and then crashed. You can run Valgrind to see what's going on before the crash.

Comment: can you include the stack trace?

Comment: for nayone still having this , i was getting this because of static compiling with gcc, parts of pthread was not getting linked.. you need -Wl,--whole-archive in that case